# How to do covert to this code block to php v7.4 or fix the syntax error

Tags: php, php-7, php-8

Currently I'm working with a laravel base ecommerce project and I got a domain mapping plugin which they provide. But the problem is it's only working on php8 or 8+, but my application runs on php v7.4.

So I wanted to convert this code block to php v7.4. There is no error while running using php v8 but run with v7.4 it gives a syntax error. Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
class Domain extends BaseModel
{
    use Crud;
    
   
    protected function url(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get:function ($value) {
                // Remove current protocol
                $value = preg_replace('#http[^:]*://#ui', '', $this->host);
                
                // Get the right protocol
                $protocol = ($this->https == 1) ? 'https' : 'http';
                
                // Use the right protocol instead
                return $protocol . '://' . $value;
            },
        );
    }
    
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | OTHER PRIVATE METHODS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
}
```

Here is the error message:

> syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' In the:
> /extras/plugins/domainmapping/app/Models/Domain.php file at line: 203

Comment: `Attribute::make(get:function ($value)...`, that `get:function` is a named argument. Those weren't introduced into PHP until 8. You need to remove the named argument and make sure you pass it in "in the old way" (in the correct order, instead of using the name `get:`.) you need to check how to call `Attribute::make()` properly. Here's all you need to know about function arguments: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the syntax error you can just remove the `get:`

i.e.

```
return Attribute::make(
        function ($value) {
            // Remove current protocol
```

..etc.

*Named arguments* like this were [introduced in PHP 8](https://stitcher.io/blog/new-in-php-8#named-arguments-rfc). They allow you to pass in values to a function by name instead of relying on the order you specify them in. It also makes it easy to skip optional parameters.

Since this function call has only one parameter specified anyway, it hopefully won't make any difference and will work correctly - unless there are optional parameters before it in the function definition. You need to check that definition before proceeding with this change.

Here's a runnable demo showing it not causing the syntax error in 7.4: https://3v4l.org/nOU3l